# Vagrant + Virtual Box Session error

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am trying to fire up a vm via Vagrant using VirtualBox. 
I got this error when I execute the command **vagrant up** (see below) using the latest versions of Virtual box 5.1.4 and Vagrant 1.7.4, therefore I downgraded Virtual box to 5.0 and Vagrant to 1.7.4 but it did not help.
I have installed the vagrant plugins vagrant-omnibus, vagrant-cashier and vagrant-berkshelf (version=4.1).
My OS is Mac OS X El Capitan and the vm that I am trying to run is a centos 6.
The final part of the output of the command "vagrant up" is:

```
    default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "63825f6b-5189-4b66-bb7a-167c7f742c49", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The VM session was aborted
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface Session
```

I googled this error and as many threads suggest I tried to restart VirtualBox, but I haven't had any success..

Below I copied the last few lines of the VM logs:

```
00:00:00.085763 APIC: Activating Local APIC
00:00:00.085782 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled APIC
00:00:00.086115 PIT: mode=3 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:00.089080 Shared Folders service loaded
00:00:00.094857 DrvBlock: Flushes will be ignored
00:00:00.094868 DrvBlock: Async flushes will be passed to the disk
00:00:00.094970 VD: VDInit finished
00:00:00.095086 AIOMgr: Endpoint for file '/Users/daniele/VirtualBox VMs/my-vm_default_1475241914862_51348/centos-6.7-x86_64-disk1.vmdk' (flags 000c0723) created successfully
00:00:00.098079 VD: Opening the disk took 3191386 ns
00:00:00.098106 AHCI: LUN#0: disk, PCHS=16383/16/63, total number of sectors 83886080
00:00:00.098115 AHCI: LUN#0: using async I/O
00:00:00.098190 AHCI#0: Reset the HBA
00:00:00.098353 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#0: no unit
00:00:00.098358 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#1: no unit
00:00:00.098376 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#2: no unit
00:00:00.098380 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#3: no unit
00:00:00.098398 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#0: finished processing RESET
00:00:00.098411 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: finished processing RESET
00:00:00.104664 NAT: Guest address guess set to 10.0.2.15 by initialization
```

I ran out of ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in VirtualBox, it is now fixed in 5.1.8.
For reference: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15687

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Solution 1:**

I'm troubleshooting the same problem but with another Linux distro. I found a workaround for Mint 18 that may work for you too.

When I go into VirtualBox, and set the troublesome VM's Settings>Network value to 'Bridged..' or 'NAT network', then the VM starts.  Further, I can browse/curl the Internet from that running VM.

[The VirtualBox forums show that others are getting this error too.](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=79000)

**Possible Solution 2:**

In my experiments, older VirtualBox versions don't have this network problem.  For example, versions 5.0.24 and 5.0.18 allow VM creation with no need for manual intervention.

**Additional Info:**

It's worth noting, that if you use Docker Toolbox, it will silently upgrade VirtualBox to whatever version it wants (e.g. Docker Toolbox 1.12.2 forces VirtualBox to 5.1.6).

At first I thought this problem was caused by VirtualBox defaulting to "NAT" as the network choice.  But that's not the cause.  VirtualBox 5.0.24 and 5.018 both use "NAT" and they work fine.